# How to attribute a single commit to multiple developers?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, bazaar

The way all version control systems I'm familiar with work is that each commit is attributed to a single developer. The rise of Agile Engineering, and specifically pair programming, has lead to a situation where two developers have made a significant contribution to the same task, a bug fix for example.

The issue of attribution won't be too much of a big deal in a work environment since the project manager will be aware of the work the pairs are doing, but what about if two open source contributors decide to pair up and push out some code to a particular project that has no idea they're working together. Is there any way for a version control system like Git to attribute a particular patch to multiple developers?

Comment: This should be split for each version control system.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
Commit title

Commit body

Co-authored-by: name <additional-dev-1@example.com>
Co-authored-by: name <additional-dev-2@example.com>
```

- Supported by [GitHub](https://github.blog/2018-01-29-commit-together-with-co-authors/) and [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/merge_requests/17919)
- Used by others: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/CommitMessageConventions

**One problem with this approach** is that you can't create a signed key for this group of devs, so you could essentially add anybody to this list even if they didn't work on a feature and GitHub would treat it as if they did. However, this shouldn't be an issue in most cases.

e.g. `Co-authored-by: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>`

With normal authors or signing groups (the old method) you would see it's not signed and know that you can't trust the commit. However, there is no signing process on co-authors.

---

Mostly outdated answer:

One solution would be to set a name for the pair:

```bash
git config user.name "Chris Wilson and John Smith"
```

Here is a related bug report with other temporary solutions:

[Bug git-core: Git should support multiple authors for a commit](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=451880)

Comment: What about if you don't know the person's Email address? Any way to link GitHub username etc?

Comment: If they made a previous commit you can just check that:
`git show <COMMIT_ID> --format=email`

Comment: This seems to already be working in GitLab (see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/merge_requests/17919)

Answer (score 78):

A git convention is to use *Co-authored-by* at the end of the commit message ([git kernel: Commit Message Conventions](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/CommitMessageConventions), referring to [Openstack Commit Messages](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/GitCommitMessages#Including_external_references)). This is also [one of the solutions](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=451880#12) on the [git-core bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=451880) linked in [Gerry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442255/12039)

```
Co-authored-by: Some One <some.one@example.foo>
```

In that comment on May 5, 2010, Josh Triplett also suggests implementing corresponding support in git.

As [Llopis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2886003) pointed out in a comment, GitHub announced support for this on their blog on Jan 29, 2018: [Commit together with co-authors](https://github.com/blog/2496-commit-together-with-co-authors) ([details](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors/)).

Comment: This is now [supported](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors/) by GitHub.

Comment: I wrote a simple git plugin to make it easier to manage these Co-authored-by trailers automatically: https://github.com/cac04/git-pair

Comment: This approach looks like a kludge (cf. [the Bazaar way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442810/673852)). And there's a principal author this way, to which the co-authors are just an addition, if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 27):

For Bazaar:

```
bzr commit --author Joe --author Alice --author Bob
```

Those names will be shown in the log separately from committer name.

Answer (score 23):

**git-pair**

https://github.com/pivotal/git_scripts#git-pair

This simple script from Pivotal to automate Git pair programming attribution.

You create a `.pairs` file like:

```
# .pairs - configuration for 'git pair'
pairs:
  # <initials>: <Firstname> <Lastname>[; <email-id>]
  eh: Edward Hieatt
  js: Josh Susser; jsusser
  sf: Serguei Filimonov; serguei
email:
  prefix: pair
  domain: pivotallabs.com
  # no_solo_prefix: true
#global: true
```

and then:

```
git pair sp js
```

sets:

```
user.name=Josh Susser & Sam Pierson
user.email=pair+jsusser+sam@pivotallabs.com
```

for you.

Comment: Unfortunately no longer maintained and does not use the proper format recognized by Github or Gitlab.

Answer (score 20):

git distinguishes between a commit's `author` and `committer` [1]. You could use it as a work-around, e.g. sign yourself as the `committer` and your co-author as the `author`:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='a' GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='a@a' git commit --author 'b <b@b>'
```

This way, both you and your co-author will be recorded in the git history. Running `git log --format=fuller`, will give you something like:

```
commit 22ef837878854ca2ecda72428834fcbcad6043a2
Author:     b <b@b>
AuthorDate: Tue Apr 12 06:53:41 2016 +0100
Commit:     a <a@a>
CommitDate: Tue Apr 12 09:18:53 2016 +0000

    Test commit.
```

[1] [Difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git)

Comment: One downside with this approach is that if one applies the change as e.g. a cherry-pick that the committer will not be kept.

Answer (score 8):

[Try git-mob](https://github.com/findmypast-oss/git-mob), we built it for attributing co-authors on commits.

E.g.

```
git mob <initials of co-authors>
git commit
git solo
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, there is an [open source project](https://github.com/nagoya-foundation/co-authored-commit), which I contribute to, on GitHub that provides a good way to do it from the command line. This project helps you to set an alias in order to create co-authored commits as follows:

`$ git co-commit -m "Commit message" --co "co-author <co-author-email>"`

Using this approach, you are able to create co-authored commits without a graphical interface.

Comment: From what I can see, this is a git alias that adds "Co-authored-by: " plus the "co-author <co-author-email>" to the end of the commit message.

Comment: Excellent piece of code here, worked flawlessly and achieved the desired effect of having a specific co-author on my PR.

Answer (score 4):

We add our names to each commit message at the end as a convention
eg : `Implemented cool feature <Aneesh | Hiren>`

Comment: This is similar to the git convention `Co-Authored-By` I mentioned in [a separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41847267/12039)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the co-author tools do not support autocompletion. You can try [git-coco](https://github.com/menaveenshankar/git-coco), its written in python3 (I'm the developer). `git-coco` supports autocomplete and auto-suggest.
Here is a snapshot
[autocomplete on sample authors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2IOp.png)