# How to create GitHub commits with multiple authors?

Tags: git, github

I sometimes want to give props to the users who designed something for me, gave me the idea, created the issue that led to a PR or submitted a PR I closed but ended up adding half of it myself.

How can I add commits that are co-authored on GitHub?

Answer (score 9):

It can be done very easily by using the [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/features/co-authors/) Software:

[image: GitHub Co Authors]

Commit together with co-authors via [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/features/co-authors/):

[image: GitHub Co Authors]

You can also read [Creating a commit with multiple authors](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors/) and [Commit together with co-authors](https://github.com/blog/2496-commit-together-with-co-authors)

> To add co-authors to a commit, just add one or more co-authored-by
>   trailers to the end of the commit message:
>
> ```
> Commit message
>
> Co-authored-by: Joel Califa <602352+califa@users.noreply.github.com>
> Co-authored-by: Matt Clark <44023+mclark@users.noreply.github.com>
> ```
>
> Include your trailers at the end of your commit message, and have at
>   least one line of white space before them.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41847267. this is just a convention and you could put those lines at the end of any commit message.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, there is an [open source project](https://github.com/nagoya-foundation/co-authored-commit), which I contribute to, on GitHub that provides a good way to do it from the command line. This project helps you to set an alias in order to create co-autored commits as follows:

`$ git co-commit -m "Commit message" --co "co-author <co-author-email>"`

Using this approach, you are able to create co-authored commits without a graphical interface.