# Are there any gitlab-way to squash any commits from feature branchs but keeping the commit owner?

Tags: git, gitlab

I use git workflow on Gitlab. There many detailed commits on my feature branch. Are there any way to let the admin to squash my commits but keeping the author?
Currently, all commits can be squash merged but using commit as admin. It makes the commit history useless.

**Update**:
I add the git logs.

```
Author: Jaron Long <***@***>
Date:   Tue Nov 24 14:53:03 2020 +0800

    Squashed commit of the following:

    commit 3889259393c68ed90d117a95baa76cf875c085a0
    Author: weitao <***@***>
    Date:   Mon Nov 23 19:50:09 2020 +0800
```

Comment: To some extent this is already handled by git. Every commit has 2 names and timestamps attached to it, author and committer. Usually the two are identical, because you made the commit, and you authored it, but in terms of rebases, squashes, etc. the two can be different. So gitlab *should* (in my opinion) honor this and use you as the author and your admin as committer, but then the next question is how logs are shown. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with gitlab, only git.

Comment: I said "to **some** extent" because obviously the squash commit will only have only have room for 2 names, the committer (the admin doing the squash) and 1 author. If a branch consists of multiple contributors then I don't know what would be the right approach.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I currently use squash-merge with --no-commit args for this. I do see the author is me not the original. I update with git logs.

Comment: GitHub and GitLab [support `Co-authored-by: ...` trailers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442255/239657).